# Field-like events and anonymous delegates

Tags: c#

When name of a field-like event `SomeNews` is used  inside a class that declares this event, this name doesn't refer to the event itself, but to the anonymous private delegate `D` created by compiler, and for that reason `D` can be invoked indirectly ( inside `MyClass` ) via `SomeNews();`

```
class MyClass
{ 
        public event MyDelegate SomeNews;
           ...
}
```

But if instead `MyClass` declares an event `SomeNews` by also specifying `add` and `remove` accessors:

```
class MyClass
{ 
        private delegate MyDelegate _someNews;
        public event MyDelegate SomeNews
        {
            add
            {
                _someNews += value;
            }

            remove
            {
                _ someNews -= value;
            }
        }

        ...
}
```

does then even inside `MyClass` the name `SomeNews` refer to the event itself and not to the underlying delegate `_someNews`? I'm assuming this since trying to invoke `_someNews` delegate via `SomeNews()` will cause a compile-time error saying "*SomeNews event can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=*"

thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you've answered your own question. Yes, when using full-bodied event syntax, referring to the event within the declaring class is no different than referring to it in any other class. This is because, like properties, the compiler has no idea what you're actually doing within the `add` and `remove` blocks.

There's nothing that says that you have to create a simple event that just adds and removes the value from an underlying delegate, or that you have to do anything with the supplied value at all. Because of this, it's not possible to "invoke" the event by simply calling it in code, since the compiler has no idea *how* to invoke the event.